# Storing a big text file into vectors and looping over it

Tags: c++, file, vector

I am making a university project and I had a question before I proceed. I have to import a **'dictionary.txt'** to the program so it can correct an other file's text.

Right now my **.txt** file is 20mb with 2 million words inside. I am storing it to a vector as soon as the program starts. It takes 2 seconds load all the words in.

*My question:* Is this the right way to import so many words inside a program? The logic behind it is that every word from the "essay" will be looped over the 2 million words until it is found and break.

Before I make this possible I would like to know if this is a bad or good way to do it and why.

Comment: No, `vector` is a very bad choice. You are looking for [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: I wonder how will a `map` help!

Comment: @CinCout with a `map` there won't be a linear search which is likely to be much faster. Please explain why a `map` will not help.

Comment: What will be the `key` and `value` in your map?

Comment: Perhaps memory map the file, maybe this will help https://github.com/johannesthoma/mmap_allocator/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @CinCout `key` will be the words of `dictionary.txt`, `value` will be dummy.

Comment: Why waste memory? Why not `sort` the `vector` once it is filled? Then `binary search` can be applied.

Comment: @MichaelWalz then a ``std::set`` might be better

Comment: @nefas actually yes.

Comment: @CinCout sorting the vector may be slow, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Theoretically, sorting is `N log N`. So is`insert` in a `map`.

Comment: `std::unordered_set`, you dont need it sorted and you want O(1) time for retrieve. Definitely not `std::map`, it holds a pair of key and value, what the key and value would be in this case?

Comment: ^ The OP wants to *find* the presence of word(s) in `dictionary`.

Comment: @CinCout but ``std::set`` (or ``std::map``) is easier to use than a sorted ``std::vector``. The choice depends on the speed constraint and the benchmark (I think vector will be faster because there is less indirection).

Comment: @nefas *"easier to use"* is a matter of choice

Comment: @CinCout I meant "_easier to use_" in the way that with the vector you have to sort and do the binary search by hand (AFAIK their is no STL function or ``std::vector`` member function that do binary search). With the ``set/map`` the ``insert`` and ``find`` member function already guaranty the expected complexity (there is no search to re-implement, ...).

Comment: @nefas You missed this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: @CinCout whats wrong with find in `std::unordered_set`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store the words themselves, std::vector is a good choice, but you should be aware of the reallocation which takes place.

If the dictionary is meant to stay at the same size you should consider reserving memory for the vector.

basically you want to do something like this:

```
void from_file(std::vector<std::string>& content, std::string pathAndFilename = "")
        {
            content.reserve(1000000) //the size your dictionary has in words

            std::fstream readContent;

            if (pathAndFilename.empty())
            {
                readContent.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
            }
            else
            {
                readContent.open(pathAndFilename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
            }

            std::string currentLine;
            while (std::getline(readContent, currentLine))
            {
                content.push_back(currentLine);
            }

            readContent.flush();
            readContent.clear();
            readContent.close();
        }
```

The problem with a vector is, searching takes really long. If you can ensure that every word in your dictionary.txt is unique, a set is the way to go since a set is a tree container and searching there is a lot faster.

You can improve the performance of the vector search if you order the vector but you won't reach anything near the map/sets performance. Nevertheless you will have to prepare the dictionary for the use with a set.

Futhermore you could split the dictionary in smaller subvectors (one for Aa one for Bb etc.). This will improve your performance even more since you can start right at the begining letter of the word you are trying to correct.

A map is not suited for this case, since a map is meant to store a key and a value. The key has to be unique as well. Ok you could use your word as key and just use an int id as value but then you can use a set as well.

Overall a vector is no bad choice and the performance should be fine for this case (even if the map will do a better job), but if you want to archieve the best performance, set is what you are looking for.

Usually a vector should be the default container and if you run into performance issues, then you can consider using a different container.